# Maintain two repos - Azure Repo and Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, azure-repos

I have an Azure Repo. I would like to use a forking workflow: fork the repo, work on branches of the fork, PR back to the upstream origin. BUT, I would like the fork to be on Bitbucket (This is for access reasons - devs have access to Bitbucket but not Azure). Is this even possible?

Would I just be better off working locally with two remotes: Bitbucket and Azure? Devs clone and work from the Bitbucket remote. When things are ready, I pull from the Bitbucket remote and push to the Azure remote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, as you mention, pull from the Bitbucket remote and push to the Azure remote.

What you would be pushing would be the feature branches made on BitBucket.

Once pushed to Azure, you can then [create a pull request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pullrequest?view=azure-devops) from within the Azure repository.

Comment: Im using GitExtensions - and I can name the origins to help keep track of what the heck is going on. But this will work nicely.